# ASP MVC DateTime problem model validation problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, datetime

I have  MS SQL in my local development server and production server. The DateTime format of my local server is "mm/dd/yyyy" but the format in production server is "dd/mm/yyyy". Every thing worked fine in my local server , but when I try to enter a date like "05/31/2010" in my production server, the Model Validation threw an error "The value '05/31/2010' is not valid for ...." since month cannot be greater than 12. I dont want to change the DateTime in either of the servers. Can some body tell me a way to get rid of this problem so that everything works fine in both of my server?

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding the [Globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx) element to the web.config - Configuration > System.web:

```
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
```

I had a similar issue - although admittedly, as a Brit, the reverse - and this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/11/21/mvc-modelbinder-and-localization.aspx) is probably what you're after, in terms of how model binding works with localization.

It's not clear where you're entering your data, but I would advise you to either *explicitly* tell the user to enter dates in one particular format, or use a calendar picker, or separate the three fields in the UI. Basically don't leave it ambiguous - you *will* get users assuming one format instead of the one you're actually using.

Note that all of this should be done well before it gets anywhere near your database - the format of your *database* should be irrelevant, as you should be using parameterized queries which only ever deal with `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset` for time-related values.

Comment: I have a Jquery datepicker which gets the date in "mm/dd/yyyy" format and I am using ASP MVC 2. I was thinking if there is anyway to know what format the SQL Server is set to and then accept the date in that format in runtime. Can that be done?